# What is the time complexity for repeatedly doubling a string?

Tags: string, algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

Consider the following piece of C++ code:

```
string s = "a";
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    s = s + s; // Concatenate s with itself.
}
```

Usually, when analyzing the time complexity of a piece of code, we would determine how much work the inner loop does, then multiply it by the number of times the outer loop runs.  However, in this case, the amount of work done by the inner loop varies from iteration to iteration, since the string being built up gets longer and longer.

How would you analyze this code to get the big-O time complexity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time complexity of this function is Θ(2<sup>n</sup>).  To see why this is, let's look at what the function does, then see how to analyze it.

For starters, let's trace through the loop for n = 3.  Before iteration 0, the string `s` is the string `"a"`.  Iteration 0 doubles the length of `s` to make `s = "aa"`.  Iteration 1 doubles the length of `s` to make `s = "aaaa"`.  Iteration 2 then doubles the length of `s` to make `s = "aaaaaaaa"`.

If you'll notice, after `k` iterations of the loop, the length of the string `s` is 2<sup>k</sup>.  This means that each iteration of the loop will take longer and longer to complete, because it will take more and more work to concatenate the string `s` with itself.  Specifically, the `k`th iteration of the loop will take time Θ(2<sup>k</sup>) to complete, because the loop iteration constructs a string of size 2<sup>k+1</sup>.

One way that we could analyze this function would be to multiply the worst-case time complexity of the inner loop by the number of loop iterations.  Since each loop iteration takes time O(2<sup>n</sup>) to finish and there are n loop iterations, we would get that this code takes time O(n · 2<sup>n</sup>) to finish.

However, it turns out that this analysis is not very good, and in fact will overestimate the time complexity of this code.  It is indeed true that this code runs in time O(n · 2<sup>n</sup>), but remember that big-O notation gives an upper bound on the runtime of a piece of code.  This means that the growth rate of this code's runtime is no greater than the growth rate of n · 2<sup>n</sup>, but it doesn't mean that this is a precise bound.  In fact, if we look at the code more precisely, we can get a better bound.

Let's begin by trying to do some better accounting for the work done.  The work in this loop can be split apart into two smaller pieces:

- The work done in the header of the loop, which increments `i` and tests whether the loop is done.
- The work done in the body of the loop, which concatenates the string with itself.

Here, when accounting for the work in these two spots, we will account for the total amount of work done across all iterations, not just in one iteration.

Let's look at the first of these - the work done by the loop header.  This will run exactly n times.  Each time, this part of the code will do only O(1) work incrementing `i`, testing it against `n`, and deciding whether to continue with the loop.  Therefore, the total work done here is Θ(n).

Now let's look at the loop body.  As we saw before, iteration k creates a string of length 2<sup>k+1</sup> on iteration k, which takes time roughly 2<sup>k+1</sup>.  If we sum this up across all iterations, we get that the work done is (roughly speaking)

> 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + ... + 2<sup>n+1</sup>.

So what is this sum?  Previously, we got a bound of O(n · 2<sup>n</sup>) by noting that

> 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>3</sup> + ... + 2<sup>n+1</sup>.
>
> < 2<sup>n+1</sup> + 2<sup>n+1</sup> + 2<sup>n+1</sup> + ... + 2<sup>n+1</sup>
>
> = n · 2<sup>n+1</sup> = 2(n · 2<sup>n</sup>) = Θ(n · 2<sup>n</sup>)

However, this is a very weak upper bound.  If we're more observant, we can recognize the original sum as the [sum of a geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum), where a = 2 and r = 2.  Given this, the sum of these terms can be worked out to be exactly

> 2<sup>n+2</sup> - 2 = 4(2<sup>n</sup>) - 2 = Θ(2<sup>n</sup>)

In other words, the total work done by the body of the loop, *across all iterations*, is Θ(2<sup>n</sup>).

The total work done by the loop is given by the work done in the loop maintenance plus the work done in the body of the loop.  This works out to Θ(2<sup>n</sup>) + Θ(n) = Θ(2<sup>n</sup>).  Therefore, the total work done by the loop is Θ(2<sup>n</sup>).  This grows very quickly, but nowhere near as rapidly as O(n · 2<sup>n</sup>), which is what our original analysis gave us.

In short, when analyzing a loop, you can always get a conservative upper bound by multiplying the number of iterations of the loop by the maximum work done on any one iteration of that loop.  However, doing a more precisely analysis can often give you a much better bound.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You have hidden assumption here on the inner string representation and concatenation operation. In this specific case the string "a...a" can be represented by much less than n times 'a' - 2 fields, counter and value are enough. Given that, the concatenation operation will be faster as well.

Comment: @icepack- That's absolutely true.  If the representation of the string used a rope, for example, this would run in linear time.